# How come threaded perl (with usethreads) isn't set by default?

Tags: multithreading, perl, compiler-options

According to the [INSTALL docs](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/perl/INSTALL#Threads),

> On some platforms, perl can be compiled with support for threads. To enable this, run
>
> ```
> sh Configure -Dusethreads
> ```
>
> The default is to compile without thread support.

With the thread implementation being pretty stable, how come it isn't a default build option? The build option seems to be set by at least Debian and Alpine Linux. Is there any good reason to build Perl without threads? What are the downsides to threaded perl?

Comment: Nevertheless Unix distributions such as FreeBSD, Debian, Ubuntu, and CloudLinux ship with Perl built with threads support usually displayed as `x86_64-linux-thread-multi`.

Comment: That can be checked with `perl -V:useithreads`. The output will be either `useithreads='define` or `useithreads='undef';`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because threaded builds of Perl are 10% slower<sup>[1]</sup> than non-threaded, non-multiplicity<sup>[2]</sup> builds.

---

1. Your experience may vary.
2. Multiplicity is supporting multiple instances of the interpreter in one program. `-DMULTIPLICITY` is implied and required by `-Dusethreads` (since each thread has its own interpreter).

Comment: Slower even if you don't `use threads`?

Comment: The threads [manual](https://perldoc.perl.org/threads) warns: _The use of interpreter-based threads in perl is officially discouraged._

Comment: @Elvin, That is not a factor. They are fully supported and safe to use. Strawberry Perl, Active Perl, and Linux distros all enable threading support, so virtually every `perl` has thread support. When asked, P5P explained the warning was there because ...people on the IRC channel got tired of handling thread-related questions. wtf.

Comment: I agree, I am all for threads in Perl. I wanted to ask you if the your "10% slower" statement applies even if we don't `use threads;` (ie. import the pragma) inside our Perl script?

Comment: By the way, unfortunately [`perlbrew`](https://perlbrew.pl/) doesn't compile with threads by default as well. I use it to install and run Perl 5.36 on Debian 11, and so does cPanel (`/usr/local/cpanel/3rdparty/bin/perl`).

Comment: @Evlin, Yes. The loss is surely do to the use of context arguments and indirects to support multiple interpreters (`-DMULTIPLICITY`). This happens whether the process has mutliple interpreters or not.

Comment: @Evlin perlbrew is silent on the matter. It passes whatever options you provide to the installer.